# Pi Model B quits working: Red PWR, pinprick green ACT LEDs

Tags: hardware

I only just got my Raspberry Pi a week ago, and it has just stopped working. When I plug it in, the red PWR leds lights up like normal and the ACT led barely lights up. I think I may have put too much voltage into the Pi, but I'm not sure whether or not that is the case. It doesn't do anything now, but the board's USB ports still seem to supply power when the Raspi is plugged in.

Can anyone help me out here? Troubleshooting? There didn't seem to be a section in the Raspi Foundations wiki specifically pertaining to my Pi. Where should I poke my multimeter leads?

Edit:Looking closely at the troubleshooting guidelines, it appears the faint green might be normal and I might just have to wait for a polyfuse. I hope this is the case. I'm still looking for suggestions.

I tested the difference between TP2 and TP1 as well as TP2 and the fuse near the SD port. There is no voltage difference.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah the ACT light flashes extremely quickly, giving the impression that it's dim. On the information you have given, I would wait for the poly-fuses to reset. This could take up to a few hours, I dont have an exact time as no one else knows exactly how long it takes. I hope it's the poly fuse.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

I left home with Transmission downloading something, and when I returned, it stuck there. When I tried to force-reboot it, the green 'ACT' light flashed and wouldn't boot.

But after several hours it worked normally as before.

So be patient, just wait, maybe it could recover when the polyfuses reset.